# Dynamically update completion list in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I find zsh's result lists for <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion quite useful, however I'd like to tweak their behaviour a bit:

They should appear when I <kbd>Tab</kbd> for the first time and afterwards dynamically update with every new letter added. The default behaviour is that the suggestions are only re-evaluated when you <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, I want to save this repeated keypress. (**Update:** But only list the possible completions, it shouldn't automatically modify my actual prompt line even if there is only one option left.)

Is there any way to achieve such behaviour?

Comment: You can get quite deep into customizing `zsh`'s behavior. What should happen exactly? At the moment this question reads like you want the choices to be *listed* for every key press after the initial TAB, but that won't actually complete anything. Should every key press behave as if it was followed by a TAB? Bear in mind that this would mean quite a bit of backspacing for unintended completions.

Comment: @user112553 The first option: In that sense, it shouldn't actually behave like a repeated TAB. I just want the suggestion list to dynamically adjust.

Answer (score 2):

I created a plugin that does exactly what you're asking for: https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete

It automatically lists completion choices as you type, without inserting them, and without needing to press any additional keyboard shortcuts. No need to press ctrl-x+i or ctrl-d or anything like that. It automatically lists everything, all the time, as long as it fits on screen.

Then, press Tab to insert the top match or press Down to start menu selection.

You can watch a demo on the page above to see if it’s what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way which might offer the solution you want, is `incremental-complete-word`:

```
zle -N incremental-complete-word
bindkey '^Xi' incremental-complete-word
```

This loads the funtion and binds it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd>. Now you can try it:

```
> k^Xi
incremental (complete): -no prefix-
```

In this example the letter `k` was typed, followed by Control-X i.

```
> kil
incremental (complete): kill
```

I typed `il` and now there was one possible completion (`kill`). One could accept that and press enter.

```
> kill^D
incremental (complete): -no prefix-
- external command -
kill      killall   killall5
```

By typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> the zsh shows possible completions.

From `zshcontrib(1)`:

> **incremental-complete-word**
>   This  allows  incremental completion of a word.  After starting this command, a list of completion choices can be  shown  after every  character you type, which you can delete with <kbd>^H</kbd> or <kbd>DEL</kbd>. Pressing return accepts the completion so far and  returns  you to normal editing (that is, the command line is not immediately executed).  You can hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> to  do  normal  completion,  <kbd>^G</kbd>  to abort  back  to  the state when you started, and <kbd>^D</kbd> to list the matches.